# 2 Relative Positioned Divs?

Tags: css, positioning, css-position

I have a container div that has relative positioning, then another div inside that also has relative positioning:

```
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
    <img src="img.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like an image with absolute positioning to be relative to the "second" div not the "first".  But I need them both to have relative positioning, how do I specify so the image is relative to the "second" div?

Comment: Why so complicated? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: complicated?  I just want an image to be relative to a closer div.

Comment: It is relative to the container that contains it. That _is_ the second div.

Comment: @Czechnology: This is true only to the extent of page hierarchy unless the parent element is given a position attribute to tell it how to handle child elements.  Otherwise it's boundaries will simply be ignored.  See my answer and the linked article below for an example.

Comment: Xtian, I hope your problem was solved.  Let us know by selecting the answer that helped.

Answer (score 3):

In the page hierarchy the image would be relative to .second; however, **you must define the parent to be relatively positioned for the child to care**.

see: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

```
.second { position:relative; }
.second img { position:absolute; top:0; left: 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is relative to the second `<div>` automatically according to the CSS standards, since it is nested in the second `<div>` and that div is positioned. Here is a quote from [the CSS2 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning):

> The containing block for a positioned box is established by the nearest positioned ancestor

So you count upwards in the DOM tree, i.e. from the nearest ancestor towards the document root, and stop at the first positioned ancestor (and if there isn't one, then it's the closest container, but that doesn't apply here). In this case, that will be `div.second` like you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
.second img{ position:absolute; top:0; left:0; }
```

The positioning is just an example; you can change it to suit your needs.

Comment: naw, it will take the parent which is .first as the relative position, not .second

Comment: Direct parent is `div.second`.